# Usar 2 models em uma View, mas separa-los no envio do formulario

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> 'AddEmployeeViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'OfficeEmployee' and no extension method 'OfficeEmployee' accepting a first argument of type 'AddEmployeeViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Dentro da View, existe um botão que abre um modal para que o usuário possa cadastrar um `Cargo` que irá popular um Select Box, esse cargo ele é cadastrado individualmente, só que na mesma tela que é cadastrado o funcionário.

Então gostaria de saber como posso separar o model de `Cargo` e `Funcionario`, visto que utilizo o mesmo controller tanto para `Cargo` quanto para `Funcionario`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é meu `AddEmployeeViewModel`:

```
public class AddEmployeeViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nome é um campo obrigatório")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "O {0} deve ter pelo menos {2} e no máximo {1} caracteres.", MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"/^[0-9]{3}.?[0-9]{3}.?[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{2}/", ErrorMessage = "CPF está em um formato inválido.")]
    public String Cpf { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^\([1-9]{2}\) (?:[2-8]|9[1-9])[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Telefone está em um formato inválido.")]
    public String Telephone { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email é um campo obrigatório")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", ErrorMessage = "Email está em um formato inválido.")]
    public String Email { get; set; }

    public long Office { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Cor é um campo obrigatório")]
    public String Color { get; set; }

    public decimal Commission { get; set; }

    public IFormFile Pic { get; set; }

    public Nullable<DateTime> BirthDate { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^\d{5}-\d{3}$", ErrorMessage = "CEP está em um formato inválido.")]
    [Display(Name = "CEP")]
    public String CEP { get; set; }

    public String UF { get; set; }

    public String Neighborhood { get; set; }

    public String City { get; set; }

    public String Address { get; set; }

    public String Number { get; set; }

    public String Complement { get; set; }
}

public class Office
{
    public String OfficeEmployee { get; set; }
}
```

e essa é a parte da View que está dando o erro:

```
<div class="modal fade none-border" id="cadastra-cargo">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Novo Cargo</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form asp-route-returnUrl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" id="cadastraCargoFuncionario" asp-action="AddOffice" asp-controller="Employee" method="post">
                <div class="form-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="control-label text-right col-md-3">Cargo: </label>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <input type="text" asp-for="OfficeEmployee" class="form-control nome">
                                    <span asp-validation-for="OfficeEmployee" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info float-r" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="$('#cadastraCargoFuncionario').submit();">Salvar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default float-l" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cara, se o model da tua view é o `AddEmployeeViewModel`, realmente ele não possui a propriedade `OfficeEmployee`. Tenta colocar o `asp-for` para o `Office.OfficeEmployee`.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com separá-los no envio? vai ter dois forms na view ou dois posts ajax para actions diferentes?

Comment: Tem 2 forms na View, para dois Actions diferentes dentro do Controller do funcionario. Exemplo `AddFuncionario` e `AddCargo`.

Comment: Da uma olhada nesses links: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1108855/ways-to-Bind-Multiple-Models-on-a-View-in-MVC e https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/multiple-models-in-single-view-in-mvc/